# Create a HTML UI form with two textboxes. Use responses in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What is need is probably fairly simple, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I need a spreadsheet with a google script that prompts a user for three values in a html form. (First name, last name, car) 
Those values need to be accessable in the rest of the script.

*The UI Service is deprecated, so I'd like to learn how do this with HTML Service*

Here is what I have so far.
I created a simple Google Script:

```
   function openForm() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('HTML');
    var firstNameRange = sheet.getRange('A1');
    var lastNameRange = sheet.getRange('A2');
    var carRange = sheet.getRange('A3');

var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Fill in this form');

 //----I want the responses of the form in 'index.html' to be used here. 
 //The openById thing is what is not working...

    var firstname = html.openById('firstname'); 
    var lastname = html.openById('lastname');
    var car = html.openById('car');

 firstNameRange.setValue(firstname);
 lastNameRange.setValue(lastname);
 carRange.setValue(car);

}
```

I also created an HTML file called 'index.html':

```
<div>
<form> First name:<br>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
<br>   Last name:<br>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
<br>   Car:<br>
<select id="car" name="Car">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbotton" onclick="google.script.host.close()">    </form>
</div>
```

[Here is an example of the script in a spreadsheet so far.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u3HykkmhyFLmZAzdDN4FVkNn9nqVWKQ_0z45eA0zfKk/edit?usp=sharing)
I'v been using multiple prompts for now, but using the answers from a HTML-form would be a big help in any next google script project.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('HTML');
```

is not working.

Should be:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('HTML-responses');
```

You are missing a `return` statement needed to open the dialog box:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Fill in this form');
  return;
```

Your `onclick` event is wrong, it's currently:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbutton" onclick="google.script.host.close()">
```

It needs to be a `google.script.run` API call:

Here is what your HTML should look like:

```
<div>
  <form> First name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
    <br>   Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
    <br>   Car:<br>
    <select id="car" name="Car">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <br><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbutton" onmouseup="writeFormData()">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  window.writeFormData = function() {
    console.log('writeFormData ran!');
    var firstNameIs = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var lastNameIs = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var carIs = document.getElementById("car").value;

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dataWasWritten)
      .processForm(firstNameIs, lastNameIs, carIs);
  };

  window.dataWasWritten = function() {
    console.log('dataWasWritten ran');
  };
</script>
```

This is what the `.gs` code should be:

```
 function onOpen() {
   //Runs when spreadsheet opens 
   openForm();
 };

 function openForm() {
   Logger.log('openForm ran!');

   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Fill in this form');
      return;
 };

 function processForm(argFirstName, argLastName, argCar) {
   Logger.log('argFirstName: ' + argFirstName);

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('HTML-responses');

   var firstNameRange = sheet.getRange('A1');
   var lastNameRange = sheet.getRange('A2');
   var carRange = sheet.getRange('A3');

   firstNameRange.setValue(argFirstName);
   lastNameRange.setValue(argLastName);
   carRange.setValue(argCar);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

suggestion:
create new google form instead of creating the form in index.html, collect its responses from the google spreadsheet into HTML again.
The help can be https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates:

```
function getData() {
//  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById(id)
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
};
```

index.html

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<table>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I understand that I could make a simple google form for what I discribed in the question. Actually, I'm making a grading system for teachers. I want to use the values they inserted in the html form in my spreadsheet for calculating students grades.  For now, I use multiple ui.prompt() dialog boxes. I figured that I could prompt the user for all values in ONE form. Is that somehow possible? Thanks anyway.